# How can I switch up a four on the floor drum rhythm?

Tags: rhythm, drums, beats

So I'm working on a song with a 4otF rhythm, but the beat gets rather boring after a while (it's a somewhat long song).  I'm looking to switch up the drums but I'm not sure I know what pattern to use or if a fill would work better, and a Jersey Club beat doesn't work with the song.  Any ideas?

[Link to demo](https://soundcloud.com/seppemane/demo-3-eden)

Comment: This is what composers and drummers are for, It's not possible to make suggestions, other than just vary the drum part, ,without knowing the context.  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some of these things to make the drums more interesting:

- Add Snare or clap on 3 and 4
- Add closed high-hats
- Add open high-hat on the off-beat (and)
- Add percussions
- Add cymbals
- Make the drums not start all at the same time. Introduce one part after another (Like 8 bars only kick, then 8 bars kick + clap, then 8 bars kick + clap + hat)
- Add parts where you dont use the drums at all (like breaks)
- Add parts where you just mute the kick drum
- After these breaks you can try to reintroduce the different drum-sounds one after another again.
- Add breakbeat-drumloops
- Make the drumpatterns not only 1 bar that repeats, make it 4 or 8 bars with some slightly variations
- Play around with some delay
- Try to use patterns of your melodie or baseline for some accents
- Try to counter some patterns of your melodie or baseline for some accents

Comment: for the breakbeat, would the amen break work?

Comment: I feel like this one works everywhere. Give it a try, I have used it many times myself. You can try mix different breaks together.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add or omit kick drum beats and add some high-hat or snare patterns to fill the space? It seems you have a kind of wobbly synth going, maybe add drum pattern that are changing in volume alongside this? However, I agree with the comment on this post from -PeterJ it depends on what kind of effect you are trying to achieve by varying the drum part.

Comment: I'm pretty much just looking for something that keeps the drums from getting boring